# To get image instead of url in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Following is relevant part of my html page, I want to get image instead of image address(`result[i].url`). Also I want to know if it is possible because I am using certain style(CSS) here.

```
function BindStudents() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/memes", success: function (result) {
                   
                    var totalCount = result.length;
                    var structureDiv = "";

                    for (let i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
                        structureDiv += "<tr>" +
                            "     <td>" + result[i].id + "</td>" +
                            "      <td>" + result[i].name + "</td>" +
                            "             <td>" + result[i].url + "</td>" +
                            "              <td>" +result[i].caption  + "</td>" +
                            "              <td><button class='btn btn-link' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this record?\",DeleteRow(" + result[i].id + "))'>Delete</button></td>" +
                            "           </tr>";
                    }
                     
                    $("#divBody").html(structureDiv);
              
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the server sends a URL then the server sends a URL.

If you want an image then you'll need to either:

- change the server-side code so it sends an image (but there is no image, file, or blob type for JSON so you'll need to encode it as text … and then write client-side code to decode the encoded image … and then find some way of displaying it … which will probably involve encoding it as a `data:` URL)
- make a send Ajax request to fetch the image from the URL you were given

---

It would probably be much simpler to just create an `<img>` element with the `src` set to the URL from the JSON when you create all the other HTML.

Comment: I would go with 2nd option, I do not want to change code for server side. For basic html I know how to fetch image. I tried this, but it didn't worked.
` <img alt="Qries" src={{result[i].url}} width="300" height="400"> `

Answer (score 0):

Just add a HTML element `<img>`:

```js
structureDiv += "<tr>" +
    "     <td>" + result[i].id + "</td>" +
    "      <td>" + result[i].name + "</td>" +
    "             <td><img src=\"" + result[i].url + "\"></td>" +
    "              <td>" +result[i].caption  + "</td>" +
    "              <td><button class='btn btn-link' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this record?\",DeleteRow(" + result[i].id + "))'>Delete</button></td>" +
    "           </tr>";
```

Comment: This works, but the image size is too much, how to adjust height and width? I tried below
`"             <td><img src=\ width="300" height="400"" " + result[i].url + "\"></td>" +`

Comment: `"<td><img src='" + result[i].url +"' width='300' height='400'"></td>" +`

Comment: I tried
 `"             <td><img src=\"" + result[i].url + "width='300' height='400' \"></td>" +` which gets converted to  `<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3573382/pexels-photo-3573382.jpeg width='300' height='400'">`  while inspecting the html.

Comment: Give it a class and adjust the size in css.

Comment: Got it! `"     <td>  <img src=\""+result[i].url+"\"    width=\"300\" width=\"400\"  >    </td>" +`